# Как исправить ошибку при установке RabbitMQ на Ubuntu 18?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

Устанавливал RabbitMQ по такой схеме:

```
$ echo "deb www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list > /dev/null
$ wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-publ...
$ sudo apt-key add rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

Но при инсталяции выдает ошибку:

> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-12-09 12:13:32 MSK; 10ms ag o
>   Process: 14198 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code= exited, status=70)
>   Process: 14197 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAIL URE)
>   Main PID: 14197 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>   Dec 09 12:13:32 192333.simplecloud.ru systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Faile d with result 'exit-code'.

На форумах нашел только что нужно изменить `/etc/hosts` и `/etc/hostname`, а как и что там менять не ясно

Comment: А почему ты добавляешь `дебиан тестинг` на `убунту`?

Comment: У них на официальном сайте для debian и ubuntu установка одна

Comment: Да ну? https://imgur.com/5K3PkNs